# Sublime Text 3 - Stop printing shell cmd, dir and path when error is raised

Tags: python-2.7, debugging, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I would like my Sublime Text to NOT print out the following extra info everytime my code throws an error.

See below for example - I do not need to see my shell_cmd, dir, or path to be printed out, just for clarity!

[image]

I have looked for a soloution but cannot seem to find one which works.

Many Thanks for any feedback!

Comment: You can edit the build system and add `"quiet": true,`. Then it will not show the command and the PATH. However it will also disable other information like the duration.

Comment: Hi @r-stein, thanks for your quick response. Could you elaborate on where I include the above command?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can edit the python build system using [PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer). Just open the build system in `Python/Python.sublime-build` and add the attribute `"quiet": true,`.

The resulting build system should look like:

```js
{
    "shell_cmd": "python -u \"$file\"",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "quiet": true,

    "variants":
    [
        {
            "name": "Syntax Check",
            "shell_cmd": "python -m py_compile \"${file}\"",
        }
    ]
}
```

However this will also suppress other outputs like the duration.